# click on element multiple times selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to give clicks on some elements that have the same id and name, after clicking on of those elements , the element disappears and then I want to click the next one. What I want to create is a loop to click on the elements and if there's no more elements with same id or name it should pass and continue the test, this is the element:

```
mark_complete = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(.,"Mark complete")]')
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
def mark_complete(self):
       while True:
             try:
               mark_complete = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(.,"Mark complete")]')
               mark_complete.click()
             except NoSuchElementException:
               break
```

Comment: this should work for a "show more" button that keeps loading more and more content, right?

Comment: Yes Anthony, just change the xpath for your element and that's all